# Show elements on page load for 5 seconds, than remove and show again on hover again, preferably CSS only

Tags: css, core-animation, opacity, keyframe, mousehover

I wish to show some info over image, I would like to show it on page load and keep it for 5 seconds, than to disappear and to reappear again on hover again (and also can stay again for min 5s, but it is not must, just to be visible again on hover).

If it helps, solution do not need to prevent elements from occupation of space when they are not visible.

This is what I have so far, it works, first part, show on page load and keep for 5 seconds:

```
    #image .details {
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;  
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

But, I can not manage to show it again and keep on hover?

Comment: If the element has disappeared on page load after 5 sec, how do your user know that they could hover it again? it's not visible anymore

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan The image would still be visible, just not the text (info)?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Yes, image is visible always, only text info over image (size, resolution in corners of image) should disappear and reappear on hover.

Answer (score 0):

You don't currently have any CSS applied on hover. I think this should achieve your desired result:

```
#image .details {
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

#image:hover .details {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You may need to adapt this depending on your HTML markup (depending on which element the cursor will actually hover over).

You should also contemplate how to make it clear that the text will be visible on hover, and how to ensure mobile users can see the text if they need to.

Comment: I tried your answer (even before I post question), but somehow nothing. Also I am thinking just to make it disappear/reappear for desktop, not for mobile users (if I manage it to reappear). Somehow CSS code for hover is not working, any change?